# renaming stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have observed the following feature when I rename a stored procedure.

```
sp_RENAME 'User_Validate', 'sp_UserValidate'
```

And when I do `sp_helptext sp_UserValidate` the procedure's name that i see is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE User_Validate  
(@userEmail nvarchar(200),  
@userPassword nvarchar(32))....
```

Why doesn't the name get updated in the stored procedure?

But when I check

```
select * from sys.procedures
```

I find the name field being updated? What's the reason behind it? The only logical conclusion I can draw is it's better to drop the procedure and recreate with a new name.

edit 1:
If I do `sp_helptext User_Validate` it returns "The object 'User_Validate' does not exist in database 'Process' or is invalid for this operation." But when I view the stored procedure the name User_Validate is still there.

Note: I know that renaming stored procedures is not a good practice, the question I asked is out of curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

`sp_helptext` does not reverse engineer the procedure, it simply shows the *original T-SQL batch* that created the procedure, including comments and white spaces.

Comment: I used sp_helptext to view the procedure and the reason I used it there is to highlight the fact that when I used sp_helptext to view what the stored procedure(code) looks like, I found the name  of the procedure did not change.. It will be foolish If I presume sp_helptext to perform some heavenly function rather than checking the context of the file. My question, is why doesn't the name in the procedure change?

Comment: In an ideal world `sp_rename` *could* go into the the text kept for the original batch, parse it, and replace the procedure name. It just doesn't, I guess is too low return of investment for development effort.

Answer (score 0):

sp_rename is not recommended for renaming stored procedures, views, triggers, and user defined functions

Your conclusion is right, you should drop and re-create it with a new name. The same is stated in BOL - [Rename a Stored Procedure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345394.aspx)

You should also check the [dependencies of a stored procedure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345404.aspx) because renaming a stored procedure may cause dependent objects to fail if they are not updated to match the change

Hope this helps